# What is the correct way to switch from os.system to Popen for spawning an interactive shell?

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to get rid of os.system in my python code, most of it is done, but I have one line which I can't seem to convert.

```
os.system('/bin/sh -i -c "/bin/runner catch exts"')
```

So far the things tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-i', '-c', '/bin/runner catch exts'])
```

That returns:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Cannot set tty process group (No such process)
```

EDIT:

Instead of running my custom runner, I've tried this with "ls" and I still get the same error.

```
os.system('/bin/sh -i -c "ls"') # works fine
```

Now trying to convert --

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-i', '-c', 'ls']) # Doesn't work
```

Returns:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Cannot set tty process group (No such process)
```

Trying (this shouldn't work, but was suggested by a user in comments):

```
p = subprocess.Popen('/bin/sh -i -c "ls"')
```

Returns:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's `/bin/runner`? How are you launching the python script?

Comment: Custom application, python is being ran normally. `python tryMe.py`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Does `/bin/runner` do anything particular with the shell/terminal/stdout?

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen('/bin/sh -i -c "/bin/runner catch exts"')` Does this work? Instead of using arguments you can try same as os.system in subprocess.

Comment: @DA14 I get a directory doesn't exist when I try that.

Comment: @DA14 Either you use `shell=True` and pass the command line as a string or you do *not* specify `shell=True` and use a list of strings (as the OP is *correctly* doing). Using a string with `shell=False` the *whole* string will be used as the *name* of the process to execute, thus failing.

Comment: @user791953 yes. You need `shell=True` i.e. `p = subprocess.Popen('/bin/sh -i -c "/bin/runner catch exts"',  shell=True)` Thanks Bakuriu.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive shells aren't possible with `Popen`. The `subprocess` module is designed to give you full control over stdin and stdout of the child process so you can talk to it.

An interactive shell, on the other hand, needs a tty (a terminal) and Python should leave its I/O streams alone. For this use case, you can try the `pty` module instead or stay with `os.system()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use subprocess.call() instead of subprocess.Popen().  Popen makes your subprocess' stdin a pipe, but sh -i wants to use its stdin as a tty.